# Can't play WebAudio MediaStream generated

Tags: webrtc

I have a problem with generating a MediaStream from an AudioContext with WebAudio for sending it to another peer with WebRTC. It turns out that when I generate the MediaStream and try to play it locally and remotely with an Audio HTML tag or JS, I don't hear anything, but I do receive the stream well.

This is my code snippet:

```
 CreateTone =
 function () {

    var ringing = 'assets/tones/ringing.wav';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', ringing , true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    request.onload = function () {
        context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function (buffer) {
            bufferAudio = buffer;
            SendTone();
        });
    }
    request.send();
};

SendTone =
function () {
   var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = bufferAudio;
    source.loop = true;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    //If I use here source.start(0); it will play

    var remote = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
    source.connect(remote);
    var streamToSend= remote.stream;
    //If I try to play this stream with an Audio element, I can't hear anything. When I send with pc.addMediaStream(streamToSend) and it's received by the other peer, it's still deaf
};
```

Am I getting the MediaStream the wrong way? Thanks in advance